# Horintal scrollview END point and start point

Tags: android

[image]

i have Horizontal scrollview with 50 controll,as i am scroll it will display 50 gracefully.but at initially user not able to understand that this is scrollview and "I need to scroll for next item". so i have simply put two image at **Right side** and **left side** as you can see in image.now my problem is "i don't able to understand that how can i invisible left side arrow to visible & invisible right side arrow".

Comment: if only hiding is problem use
imageview.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);

Comment: i know that how to invisible any control but can you elaborate that how to invisible at the 50 number item

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* I just realized how old this post is, but maybe it will help someone in the future.

Alright this is my first post so hopefully I can format it correctly. I actually had this exact same problem so I'll post my solution for it. I used images for the arrows.

```
hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.HorizontalScrollView);
left_arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow);
right_arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);

hsv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Checks if your horizontalscrollview can scroll left
        if (!hsv.canScrollHorizontally(-1))
        {
             left_arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          
        }
        else
        {
             left_arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //Checks if the horizontalscrollview can scroll right
        if(!hsv.canScrollHorizontally(1)) 
        {
             right_arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
             right_arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }                   
    }
 });
```

I put this in my onCreate method and it works like a charm. The listener checks when you scroll and the canScrollHorizontally uses a postive / negative integer to determine if the view can scroll any more. Positive for right, negative for left.